# Both strings should be equal?

Tags: java, string

```
String s1 = "learn";
String s1 = s1+"Java";
```

now s1 is pointing to `"learnJava"` string right ?

```
String s2 = "learnJava";
```

`if(s1 == s2)` is false. WHY ?

`s2` should point to same `"learnJava"` as its already present in StringConstantPool(s1).

Comment: Why did you change the strings in the question? That immediately makes my answer less useful, but doesn't make your question any better...

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer Jon. Actually I wanted to just edit the string literal and I edited it without seeing your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> s2 should point to same "learnJava" as its already present in StringConstantPool.

Nope - the string pool is only used for *constant* strings unless you call `intern`.

So the string pool contains `"learn"`, `"Java"` and `"learnJava"`... but `s1` refers to a string *not* in the string pool, because the concatenation is performed at execution time.

If you had a compile-time constant expression, it would be different:

```
String s1 = "learn" + "Java"; // Constant expression
String s2 = "learnJava";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true, guaranteed
```

Or if you want to keep your execution-time concatenation:

```
String s1 = "learn";
s1 += "Java";
s1 = s1.intern();
String s2 = "learnJava";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
```

In general though, just don't compare strings with `==`... it's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: So in this case `s1` is not refering to string pool. Will `s2` refer to string pool?

Comment: @hitz: Well the *first* value of `s1` is a reference to an entry in the pool - but the second isn't, because it's the result of a concatenation. But yes, in all these cases `s2` refers to a value in the string pool, because it's initialized with a compile-time constant expression.

Comment: So if we do `s1.intern();` it means there are two same string one in heap and other in pool?

Comment: @codegasmer: Yes, that's right - although the one in the heap can be garbage collected if nothing else refers to it.

Comment: thaks for the clarification, and also I been folllowing your other java threads you are very helpful I know thanku you comments are not allowed but cant stop, thanks again for sharing  your knowledge,god bless you

Comment: To complete the last thought of this Answer… Call either of these [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods for an equality test, [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) or [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that came up for me as well.
A char: 'a' is a primitive
A Character: new Character('a') is an object
A String: "a" is an object
The reason that "learnJava" != "learnJava" is that they are different objects.
So, in order to check if two strings are equal, you have to do:

```
String s1 = "learnJava";
String s2 = "learnJava";
s1.equals(s2) > true
```