# Why Concatenation of two string objects reference not equal to same content string object

Tags: java, string

Why below `s3` and `s5` `String` objects are differ, When `s5` try to created in String pool it checks content `s3` already have same content so `s5` refers `s3` object in string pool. But my assumption is wrong, then any one correct me.

```
String s1 = "Buggy";
String s2 = "Bread";
       
String s3 = "BuggyBread";
      
String s4 = "Buggy" + "Bread"; 
String s5 = s1 + s2 
System.out.println(s3 == s4); // True
System.out.println(s3 == s5); //false
```

Comment: s5 isn't in the string pool.

Comment: read @Jon Skeet answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30264214/3841803). `the string pool is only used for constant strings unless you call intern.` so `s3` is in pool and `s5` is in heap

Answer (score 9):

1. `String s4 = "Buggy" + "Bread";`

   The compiler is smart enough to realize this is just the constant `BuggyBread` which is already referenced in `s3`. In other words, `s4` references the same `String` as `s3` that is in the string pool.
2. `String s5 = s1 + s2;`

   Here the compiler faithfully translates to a `StringBuilder`-based concatenation of the contents of the variables, which yields a difference reference than `s3`. In other words, this is similar to:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1);     
   sb.append(s2);
   String s5 = sb.toString();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Just try this   
  String s = "Buggy";
  s = s.concat("Bread");
  System.out.println(s);
```